# Regex Group, problems with catching IPs

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-group

I post slightly changed Logs down.

I have an regex to match 3 different groups in one log line, i match the Time, the ip and the messages that the SMTP server recieved.

i tryed it with the following regex
(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})..disconnected.?\s+(\d+) message[s]

The problem is only the 2. Group with the IP`s to show you the problem
in the first line the ip is 11.132.8.61 what regexr cathces is only 1.132.8.6
so he leaves some numbers out. I thought with the \d{1,3} he will match all three or two numbers if there is more than one, he also does is in the second bracket but not in the first or last.

```
[16A4:000C-0780] 01.12.2020 01:00:07   SMTP Server: 11.132.8.61 disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[16A4:000E-07F8] 01.12.2020 01:00:07   SMTP Server: 11.132.8.61 disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[16A4:000E-0780] 01.12.2020 01:00:07   SMTP Server: 11.132.8.61 disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[16A4:000C-0780] 01.12.2020 01:00:07   SMTP Server: 11.132.8.61 disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[16A4:000C-07F8] 01.12.2020 01:00:08   SMTP Server: 11.132.8.61 disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[16A4:000C-0780] 01.12.2020 01:04:51   SMTP Server: 11.132.8.61 disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[16A4:000C-07F8] 01.12.2020 01:30:46   SMTP Server: 11.132.8.61 disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[16A4:000C-0780] 01.12.2020 01:30:46   SMTP Server: 11.132.8.61 disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[16A4:000E-0780] 01.12.2020 01:33:25   SMTP Server: 11.132.8.61 disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[16A4:000C-07F8] 01.12.2020 01:33:25   SMTP Server: 11.132.8.61 disconnected. 1 message[s] received

[12CC:0015-118C] 30.11.2020 05:08:59   SMTP Server: bsicip01.dd.example.com (12.99.81.53) disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[12CC:000B-118C] 30.11.2020 05:08:59   SMTP Server: bsicip01.dd.example.com (12.99.81.53) disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[12CC:000F-0FF0] 30.11.2020 05:08:59   SMTP Server: bsicip01.dd.example.com (12.99.81.53) disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[12CC:000F-120C] 30.11.2020 05:10:05   SMTP Server: bsicip03.dd.example.com (12.99.81.53) disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[12CC:0015-118C] 30.11.2020 05:10:05   SMTP Server: bsicip01.dd.example.com (12.99.81.53) disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[12CC:0014-118C] 30.11.2020 05:10:05   SMTP Server: bsicip01.dd.example.com (12.99.81.53) disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[12CC:000B-120C] 30.11.2020 05:10:05   SMTP Server: bsicip01.dd.example.com (12.99.81.53) disconnected. 1 message[s] received
[12CC:000A-120C] 30.11.2020 05:10:05   SMTP Server: bsicip01.dd.example.com (12.99.81.53) disconnected. 1 message[s] received
```

```
The expected out-put would be 
match[1] = 01.12.2020 01:00:07
match[2] = 11.132.8.61
match[3] = 1
```

Comment: Could you please post sample of expected output in your question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 added it at the bottom now

Comment: have you thot about just using various splits? it looks like you could use `-split` on several very predictable patterns and grab the desired info from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `.*` to **`.*?`** (or, given that that you can expect least one character to occur between the capture groups, `.+?`) to make the subexpression **non-greedy**.

That way, `.*` doesn't "steal" up to two leading digits from the what the following `\d{1,3}`subexpression matches.

To give a simple example:

```sh
# !! BROKEN: greedy.
PS> if (' 123' -match '.*(\d{1,3})') { $Matches[1] }

3 # !! Only the LAST digit matched, because .* matched as much as it
  # !! could while still matching \d{1,3}
```

```sh
# OK: non-greedy.
PS> if (' 123' -match '.*?(\d{1,3})') { $Matches[1] }

123 # OK - all 3 digits matched, because .*? matched as little as it
    # could while still matching \d{1,3}
```

---

To put it all together (note that I'm using `.+?`, also in lieu of `..` before `disconnected`):

```
'[16A4:000C-0780] 01.12.2020 01:00:07   SMTP Server: 11.132.8.61 disconnected. 1 message[s] received',
'[12CC:0015-118C] 30.11.2020 05:08:59   SMTP Server: bsicip01.dd.example.com (12.99.81.53) disconnected. 1 message[s] received' |
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).+?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).+?disconnected\.?\s+(\d+) message\[s\]') {
      [pscustomobject] @{
        Count = $Matches[3]
        Timestamp = $Matches[1]
        IP = $Matches[2]
      }
    }
  }
```

The above yields:

```
Count Timestamp           IP
----- ---------           --
1     01.12.2020 01:00:07 11.132.8.61
1     30.11.2020 05:08:59 12.99.81.53
```

Note:

- In general (it may not be necessary in your case), you could make the regex more robust by using word-boundary assertions, `\b`, around subexpressions such as `.\d{1,3}` so that they don't accidentally match inside *longer* runs of digits, or you could explicitly stipulate that a *non*-digit (`\D`) precede and follow.

---

**Alternative solution using the `-split` operator**:

As [Lee Daley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) points out, you could use `-split`, the [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) to split your lines into fields, as a conceptually simpler alternative to regexes:

```
'[16A4:000C-0780] 01.12.2020 01:00:07   SMTP Server: 11.132.8.61 disconnected. 1 message[s] received',
'[12CC:0015-118C] 30.11.2020 05:08:59   SMTP Server: bsicip01.dd.example.com (12.99.81.53) disconnected. 1 message[s] received' |
  ForEach-Object {
    $fields = -split $_
    if ($fields[-4] -eq 'disconnected.') {
      [pscustomobject] @{
        Count     = $fields[-3]
        Timestamp = '{0} {1}' -f $fields[1], $fields[2]
        IP        = $fields[-5].Trim('()')
      }
    }
  }
```

The above yields the same as the regex-based solution.

Comment: i changed it to `(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*?(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})*?.disconnected.?\s+(\d+) message` now it works for the first part of my log lines, but not for the second part where the ips are in brackets.

Comment: The output you posted still contains the problem of the beginning in 11.132.8.6 it should be .61 but i tried in script and for the second one (the one with brackets) it works just fine

Comment: Good point, @Trippin, that came from the `..` in your original regex. The simplest solution is to replace both `.*` and  `..` with `.+?`. Please see my update.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, @Trippin. Please also see the `-split`-based alternative I've just added to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following regex. This will create 3 capturing groups which will have values in them to grab later on.

```
^\[\S+\s+(\d{1,2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})\s+(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\s+SMTP\s+Server:\s*(?:\S+\s*\()?((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\)?\s+[\w.-]+\s+(\d+).*$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/hD9QZ8/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^\[\S+\s+                ##Matching from starting [ 1 or more non-space occurrence(s) followed by 1 or more occurrences of spaces.
(\d{1,2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})  ##Creating 1st capturing group which matches 1 to 2 digits followed by DOT followed by 2 digits followed by dot followed by 4 digits.
\s+(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}    ##Matching 1 or more occurrences of spaces, then matching (2 digits colon)'s 2 occurrences followed by 2 digits here.
\s+SMTP\s+Server:\s*     ##Matching 1 or more spaces followed by SMTP 1 or more spaces followed by Server: spaces.
(?:\S+\s*\()?            ##In a non-capturing group matching 1 or more non-spaces followed by 0 or more spaces match ( keeping it optional.
((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\)?     ##Creating 2nd capturing group which has digits in it.
\s+[\w.-]+\s+            ##Matching spaces \w.- 1 or more occurrences followed by spaces.
(\d+)                    ##Creating 3rd capturing group which has digits in it.
.*$                      ##Matching anything till end of value.
```

Comment: I tryed it on regex101 there it matches the correct groups from the first segment of my example log, but in the second one where the servernames are in front of the ips and the ips are in brackets it doesnt match anything

Comment: @Trippin, in regex101 site you need to use like: `^\[\S+\s+(\d{1,2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})\s+(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\s+SMTP\s+Server:\s+((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\s+[\w.-]+\s+(\d+)\s+\S+[^\n$]*`(mentioned in [DEMO link in my answer](https://regex101.com/r/eMMCw9/1) ) we need to give `\n` in site ONLY to avoid taking it whole text as a single line, that's site bug, but in actual code you need to user regex mentioned in my answer only. check it once and let me know then.

Comment: i tried it in my powershell script now, without the \n, there it matched only the Lines without the IP in Brackets, then i used ```^\[\S+\s+(\d{1,2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})\s+(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\s+SMTP\s+Server:\s+((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\s+[\w.-]+\s+(\d+)\s+\S+$``` which you wrote above, but i dont get any matcehs there at all

Comment: @Trippin, Ok, to catch both cases mentioned by you, I am come up with following code now: `^\[\S+\s+(\d{1,2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})\s+(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\s+SMTP\s+Server:\s*(?:\S+\s*\()?((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\)?\s+[\w.-]+\s+(\d+).*$` [New regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hD9QZ8/1) please try this once and let me know if this helps you. Once you confirm then only I will edit my answer.

Comment: it works now thank you very much, could you include the time behind the Date format into the first match, i use it later on.